# Defining a derived mode breaks a feature that worked in the parent mode

Tags: org-mode, org-ref, derived-mode

In `org-ref` there is a feature whereby when the cursor is on a citation link, the information about the citation appears in the echo area. The feature is implemented using idle timers.

I have defined my mode as follows:

```
(define-derived-mode my-test-mode org-mode "MyTest"
  "My test mode."
  )
```

When I put an `org` buffer containing an `org-ref` citation link into the new mode, the mentioned feature stops working.

In the `org-ref` code, the feature is enabled by the following lines (not inside a `defun`):

```
(when org-ref-show-citation-on-enter
  (org-ref-show-link-messages))
```

I tried putting `(org-ref-show-link-messages)` in my mode definition, but that did not help. In case this is relevant, here is the code of that function:

```
(defun org-ref-show-link-messages ()
  "Turn on link messages.
You will see a message in the minibuffer when on a cite, ref or
label link."
  (interactive)
  (or org-ref-message-timer
      (setq org-ref-message-timer
            (run-with-idle-timer 0.5 t 'org-ref-link-message))))
```

So, what am I missing?

Comment: I think you'll need to debug this, or else provide more details. (And I'm guessing that the info appears in the echo area, not the minibuffer. Or is the minibuffer active at the time you see the info?)

Comment: @Drew I provided some details. Please let me know if there is any other way I can improve the question. (I think you are right as the minibuffer is not active; however, the docstring states that the minibuffer is used.)

Comment: Are you sure org-ref is active in your derived mode? org-ref might be set up to activate only in org-mode buffers.

Comment: @Tyler What do you mean by being "active"? It is not a minor mode. `org-ref` is loaded in my `.emacs`. Furthermore, `org-ref` citations are org-links, which do work in the mode derived from `org-mode`.

Comment: I see. Not sure how org-ref is structured if it's not a minor mode. If it modifies or extends org-mode features, it may not do anything in non-org-mode buffers.